# Swift - remove/add UIView from superView

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

In my project I have `UIView` called `MakeWishView` which I let appear by the tap of a button like this:

```
@objc private func addWishButtonTapped(){
    print("addWishButton tapped")
    
    view.addSubview(makeWishView)
    
    makeWishView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
    makeWishView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    makeWishView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    makeWishView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    
    makeWishView.grayView.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
    makeWishView.visualEffectView.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.grayView.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.wishButton.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.closeButton.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.dropDownButton.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.wishNameTextField.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.wishImage.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.wishImageButton.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.linkTextField.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.priceTextField.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.noteTextField.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.linkImage.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.priceImage.alpha = 0
    makeWishView.noteImage.alpha = 0
    
        
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        
        self.makeWishView.visualEffectView.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.grayView.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.wishButton.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.closeButton.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.dropDownButton.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.wishNameTextField.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.wishImage.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.wishImageButton.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.linkTextField.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.priceTextField.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.noteTextField.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.linkImage.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.priceImage.alpha = 1
        self.makeWishView.noteImage.alpha = 1
        
        self.makeWishView.grayView.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }
    
}
```

And I dismiss the view like this:

```
func dismissView(){
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
        self.grayView.transform =  CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.3, y: 1.3)
        self.visualEffectView.alpha = 0
        self.grayView.alpha = 0
        self.wishButton.alpha = 0
        self.closeButton.alpha = 0
        self.dropDownButton.alpha = 0
        self.wishNameTextField.alpha = 0
        self.wishImage.alpha = 0
        self.wishImageButton.alpha = 0
        self.linkTextField.alpha = 0
        self.priceTextField.alpha = 0
        self.noteTextField.alpha = 0
        self.linkImage.alpha = 0
        self.priceImage.alpha = 0
        self.noteImage.alpha = 0
    }) { (_) in
        self.visualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.grayView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.wishButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.dropDownButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.wishNameTextField.removeFromSuperview()
        self.wishImage.removeFromSuperview()
        self.wishImageButton.removeFromSuperview()
        self.linkTextField.removeFromSuperview()
        self.priceTextField.removeFromSuperview()
        self.noteTextField.removeFromSuperview()
        self.linkImage.removeFromSuperview()
        self.priceImage.removeFromSuperview()
        self.noteImage.removeFromSuperview()
        self.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

The problem is that if I want click on the `addWishButton` again the `MakeWishView` does not get displayed but instead an empty `view`:

[image]

I guess I am having a simple misunderstanding on how to dismiss or add a `UIView`. Appreciate any help :)

Comment: Is `dismissView` written in the `MakeWishView` class or your view controller class?

Comment: in `MakeWishView`

Comment: dismissing once works. But adding again does not work

Comment: So when `dismissView` is called, you never actually remove `makeWishView` from _its_ superview? And you never set the alphas back to 1?

Comment: i thought I remove `makeWishView` by calling `self.removeFromSuperView()`

Comment: Did you set the alphas of the subviews of `makeWishView` back to 1, when you are adding it back?

Comment: yes I am. I will update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove the subviews here

```
    self.visualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.grayView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.dropDownButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishNameTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishImageButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.linkTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.priceTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.noteTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.linkImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.priceImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.noteImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromSuperview()
```

You need to make the declare of the view a computed property instead of a stored one like

```
var makeWishView:MakeWishView {
     ....
    return 
}
```

or do this only inside the animation completion

```
 self.removeFromSuperView()
```

and set back alpha  = 1

Comment: what exactly do you mean by that? I am calling `self.removeFromSuperView`

Comment: I updated my question. I actually set back alpha to 1

Comment: the object `makeWishView` inside you vc contains all the subviews in first click so it appears correctly when you dismiss it in completion you remove the subviews of that same object so when you add it again it's empty as you actually removed the subviews not only set their alpha to 0

Comment: They meant that you don't need to remove all the subviews from super views. Just remove the whole `MakeWishView` from super view, and its subviews will be removed automatically.

Comment: @Chris set them to 1 not 0

Answer (score 1):

Why do you remove the following views from their superview ? I couldn't see that you  add them again

```
{ (_) in
    self.visualEffectView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.grayView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.closeButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.dropDownButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishNameTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.wishImageButton.removeFromSuperview()
    self.linkTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.priceTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.noteTextField.removeFromSuperview()
    self.linkImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.priceImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.noteImage.removeFromSuperview()
    self.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I think you just need to call the following instead:

```
{ (_) in

    self.removeFromSuperview()

}
```

Comment: yep that was my mistake as the answer above already suggested :) Thanks!

Comment: Best of Luck :)